# MySQL COUNT in two tables same time

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My question is not so hard, i just really can't find the answer anywhere.

I've got 3 tables.

`webshops`, `webshop_category` and `webshop_item`.

My query is:

```
SELECT webshops.id, webshops.name, webshops.tax, webshops.contact_name, webshops.contact_email, webshops.contact_phone, webshops.contact_address, COUNT(webshop_category.id), COUNT(webshop_item.id) 
FROM webshops, webshop_category, webshop_item 
WHERE webshops.id = webshop_category.ws_id AND webshop_category.id = webshop_item.ws_category
GROUP BY webshops.id
```

My #1 webshop got 2 categories with 4 items. But with this query it says:

```
id  ...  COUNT(webshop_category.id)  COUNT(webshop_item.id)
 1                    4                         4
```

But i just have 2 categories. So i'd like it to be:

```
id  ...  COUNT(webshop_category.id)  COUNT(webshop_item.id)
 1                    2                         4
```

How can i do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a COUNT(DISTINCT webshop_category.id) that should do it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

put a distinct inside the count like:

```
SELECT webshops.id, webshops.name, webshops.tax, webshops.contact_name, webshops.contact_email, webshops.contact_phone, webshops.contact_address, COUNT(DISTINCT webshop_category.id), COUNT(webshop_item.id) 
FROM webshops, webshop_category, webshop_item 
WHERE webshops.id = webshop_category.ws_id AND webshop_category.id = webshop_item.ws_category
GROUP BY webshops.id
```

Comment: (+1) DISTINCT inside the COUNT should do it.